# Show the location or address bar in Android WebView?

Tags: android

There are posts all over the internet about how to hide the address bar in a WebView, but by default the WebView activity does hide the address bar. I'm interested in actually *showing* the address bar on a WebView inside my own Activity. However, I don't want to pop out to the default browser, because I am using my own `WebViewClient` which utilizes `onPageStarted` to detect when a success URL is reached and `finish()` back to the parent activity.

I want the address bar to show the user that they are actually at the URL they think they are so that they don't accuse me of phishing. **Is there a way to have a `WebView` show its address bar with its current URL?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebView ["does not include any features of a fully developed web browser, such as navigation controls or an address bar"](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) as per the developer docs.

You could implement a toast or alike to show where the user is being tacking...?